# Facebook Video Plays and Photo views

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-insights

page_video_plays and page_photo_views are deprecated from the insights usually when this happens there is a different way you can get that data, does anyone know how I can keep getting this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case somebody is searching for this, check [Metric Substitution](http://searchenginewatch.com/article/2144673/Facebook-Deprecating-50-Page-Insights-Metrics-Are-You-Ready)

it has some replacement for deprecated metrics

Ex. Video_plays can be obtained from page_consumptions_by_consumption_type